# Django template url link not working

Tags: python, django

I am creating an app in django for the classroom information. The index.html displays the list of teacher names. on click it goes to the details page with teacher and class information. 
But the link refers to the home page only and not taking the teacher_name as parameter. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Here are my code. 
index.html:

```
{% if Teacher_details %}
<ul>
{% for teacher in Teacher_details %}
<li>
<a href="/teacher/{{teacher.Teacher_Name}}/">
 {{ teacher.Teacher_Name }} &nbsp; {{teacher.Teacher_Name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No Teacher details are available.</p>
  {% endif %}
```

app/url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^(?P<Teacher_Name>)/$', views.teacher_view, name="details"),
]
```

app/views.py

```
# all the href goes to index instead of teacher_view.
def index(request):
    Teacher_details=Teacher_data.objects.all()
    t=loader.get_template('index.html')
    c={'Teacher_details':Teacher_details}
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c,request))
def teacher_view(request,Teacher_Name):
    t=loader.get_template('details.html')
    c={'Teacher_details':Teacher_Name}
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c,request))
```

Example: 
   'teacher/max' from the html page should go to details.html page with 'max' as variable. 
  I can see that link in my address bar. but it only goes to  index.html.

Comment: The file called `app/urls.py`, right? Do you have the project-level `urls.py`? - please post it's contents also. Thanks.

Comment: do yourself a favor and avoid hardcoding urls in templates, instead use the {% url %} tag, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: This is my project level urls.py                                                                   from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^teacher/', include('teacher.urls')),      
]                                                                                                                                       teacher is my app name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
url(r'^(?P<Teacher_Name>[W]+)/$', views.teacher_view, name="details"),
```

Comment: I changed the code to  url(r'^(?P<Teacher_Name>[^/]+)/$', views.teacher_view, name="details"),
 Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression ^(?P)/$ I think that does not match any name. You could use something like ^(?P[^/]+)/$.

Comment: Thank you changing  the regular expression as you said fixed my problem. Now it loads the required page.